# How to print SAS record basing on the max value for a variable

Tags: sas, max

I have a dataset like this:

```
name  age  sex region
Paul   60   M     1
Emily  42   F     2
Laura  60   F     2
Brad   48   M     1
Linda  58   F     3
```

I would like to print the record with maximum value for age, but there are two records with same value (Paul and Laura have same maximum age =60).

How to print an output like this (excluding region variable):

```
name  age  sex
Paul   60   M
Laura  60   F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input name $ age sex $ region;
datalineS;
Paul   60   M     1
Emily  42   F     2
Laura  60   F     2
Brad   48   M     1
Linda  58   F     3
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select * from have
   having max(age) = age;
quit;
```